# Using the Google Translate API v2 via a proxy server

Tags: perl, google-translate

I have a perl script that calls the Google Translate API v2.  I have a key and this script works fine at home.  It fails at work though and the only difference is that I'm on a VPN and must use a proxy server at work. My perl script sets the proxy server and it has been tested with many URLs and no problems connecting to any of them.  I also tested this same script with the BableFish Translate API and again the script works fine at work.   But, all attempts to reach the Google Translate API v2 fail at work.

The failure message is:

> "failed: Translation back-end failed; unsuccessful languages call: 500
>   Connect failed: connect: Connection timed out; Connection timed out at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10/Lingua/Translate/Google.pm line 246"

Any ideas on why the script fails only with the Google Translate API v2 when at work?
Any suggestions on how to debug?

**Here is my Key Admin**

Key for server apps (with IP locking)
API key: ..deleted for security..
IPs:    Any IP allowed
Activated on:   Jan 31, 2012 2:39 PM
Activated by:    you

Comment: Does the requested url work with a browser?

Comment: Yes, the URL using the Google Translate API v2 does work with a browser that is using the same proxy server.  I found this strange that it worked with the browser but not with the program.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the proxy removes/alters one or more headers in the request.

Try connecting to the link with mozilla, and use Live Httpd header plugin to check out the headers set and received at home and $work.

Print out the headers in your script at home and at $work and search for differences.

Regards,

Comment: I too thought that this could be an issue with a header being modified. As you can read above, the Google Translate API URL does work with a browser at work.  Of course the browser is using the same proxy server as my program.  I was hoping to find some Web page that I can connect to with my program that would bring the headers received.  Then I can do as you suggest, that is try the program at work and at home to see if the headers match.  Do you know any websites that would print the incoming headers?

Comment: I finally got it working.  I was only setting http_proxy but Google Translate API uses https_proxy.  Also, I deleted "$ua->env_proxy".  After those two changes everything works.